# Geometric meaning of a curvature equation

Tags: riemannian-geometry

In Do Carmo's differential geometry, he proves a lemma about Riemannian curvature tensor.

> Let $f: A\in \mathbb R^2 \to M$ be a parametrized surface and let $(s,t)$ be the usual coordinates of $\mathbb R^2$. Let $V=V(s,t)$ be a vector field along  $f$. For each $(s,t)$, it is possible to define $R(\frac{\partial f}{\partial s},\frac{\partial f}{\partial t})V$ in an obvious manner.
>
> 4.1 Lemma.
> $$\frac{D }{\partial t}\frac{D }{\partial s}V-\frac{D }{\partial s}\frac{D }{\partial t}V=R(\frac{\partial f}{\partial s},\frac{\partial f}{\partial t})V$$

I'm looking for a geometric explanation of this equality. The only thing I can relate to this equality is when $V$ the velocity field along a geodesic. In this case, the second term is 0 and this gives Jacobi equation. But is there any geometric meaning behind the equation alone?

Comment: You might want to see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809324/visual-explanation-of-the-indices-of-the-riemann-curvature-tensor/1809362#1809362). The Riemann tensor is roughly a measure of how parallel transport fails to commute, which is in turn a measurement of curvature. The corresponding [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) should also be useful.